# How to check a checkbox (like it was checked manually)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a list of check boxes (having class `checkbox`). Different tasks are assigned to different check box. Clicking on one check box does something and clicking on another does something else.

Now i want to make a check box which should mark all the check boxes(with class `checkbox`) as checked.
So i created a new check box and used the following code to mark all other check boxes

```
$(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
```

It ,indeed ,marked all my check boxes, but the problem is that it doesn’t initiate the events and functions associated with those check boxes.

How to do that?

Here's the full code

```
$("#check_all").change(function(){

    //If it was checked
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
        $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);           
    }

    //If it was unchecked
    else {
        $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: try $(".list").trigger("change");

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Eh? What is the point of that?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi it checks/unchecks checkboxes, but no events are raised

Comment: Can anyone explain why there are 3 negative votes? I didn't give events detail because there are plenty of them. AJAX, sorting, ordering etc

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger `click` event:

```
$("#check_all").change(function(){
    $(".checkbox")
       .prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'))
       .trigger('click');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/Y9rcL/3/)

Comment: `$(this).prop('checked')` is a redundant version of `this.checked`.

Comment: What if `$('#check_all')` is given the `.checkbox` class by mistake, or what if some other piece of code binds an event listener to the click event to any one of the `.checkbox` elements? Why even click those elements?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem from my personal experience, when i change state of checkbox, i want to trigger exactly same events as clicking on it. Else you have to trigger specific events manually (i don't know any about event in question)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do what you need to do would be this:

```
$('#checkAll').on('click', function()
{
    var all;
    if (this.checked)
        all = $('.checkbox').not(':checked');
    else
        all = $('.checkbox:checked');
    all.prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

It works, as you can see [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TD44e/)

How it works is simple:

`this.checked` tells me what the check state of the *"check all"* element is. If it's checked, then those other checkboxes that aren't checked should alter state. If `this.checked` is false, I have to uncheck all checked checkboxes.
That means I have to use 2 distinct selection methods: `$('.checkbox:checked')` gives me all checked elements, while `$('.checkbox').not(':checked')` gives me the oposite.

I update the selected elements by simply passing the check-state of the master controle (`$('#checkAll')`) element to the `$.prop` method: